# p-Sylow Subgroups for group of order $\lvert G\rvert = kp$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Suppose a group $G$ has order $\lvert G \rvert = kp$ with $p$ a prime and $p \nmid k$. Is it true that $p-1$ elements of the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ have order $p$?

My reasoning is as follows; by the first Sylow theorem, if $\lvert G \rvert = p^rk$ then there exists a $p$-Sylow subgroup of order $p^r$. If $r = 1$ then there is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of order $p$. Since these groups are $p$-subgroups, each of their elements has order $p^\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb Z$, but since the order of the $p$-Sylow subgroups is $p$ and the only element in a group of order $1$ is the identity, the remaining $p-1$ elements must have order $p$ (since their order cannot exceed the order of the group).

Comment: @ArpanSadhukhan Cyclic groups don't ONLY have elements of order equal to the order of the group. I wasn't sure about the case for groups of prime order, so I asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In any group of prime order $p$, all the non-identity elements have order $p$.